# hockeyapp plugin and jenkins pipeline and hockey app URL

Tags: android, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, hockeyapp

I am using a declarative pipeline and in a stage I have a step using Hockey app to upload an APK.  It works fine, but I can not seem to get the URL to the HockeyApp version.  Supposedly its in an environment var HOCKEYAPP_INSTALL_URL, but alas, it is not. My question is how to get this URL to the version in HocekyApp?

```
 step([$class: 'HockeyappRecorder',
 applications: [[downloadAllowed: false, mandatory: false, 
 notifyTeam: false, releaseNotesMethod: [$class: 'NoReleaseNotes'],
 uploadMethod: [$class: 'AppCreation', publicPage: false]]],
 debugMode: false, failGracefully: false])
```

Comment: I've also tried this.
I used both `env. HOCKEYAPP_INSTALL_URL` and `env. HOCKEYAPP_INSTALL_URL_<app_index>` but when I echo it, it's null

Comment: looks like this PR will fix it  https://github.com/jenkinsci/hockeyapp-plugin/pull/46